# GUI for statsd data other than Graphite?

Tags: data-visualization, metrics, graphite

I just installed graphite/statsd for production use. I'm really happy with it, but one of my co-workers asked me if there was a way to make it look prettier. Honestly, I can't say that I haven't wonder the same.

Are there alternatives to the Graphite UI that do a better job rendering data, perhaps using one of the awesome frontend graphing libraries and http push?

Comment: By the way, strictly speaking, there is no such thing as *statsd data*. Statsd is just a proxy that aggregates incoming requests, actual storing is done by Whisper or any other graphite backend, which is what you probably meant.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

On the latest [Graphite docs page](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tools.html), there is a list of tools which work with Graphite. For reference, here are the ones which seem to be prettification-based:

- [Charcoal](https://github.com/cebailey59/charcoal)
- [Descartes](https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes)
- [GDash](https://github.com/ripienaar/gdash.git)
- [Giraffe](http://kenhub.github.com/giraffe/)
- [Graphitus](https://github.com/erezmazor/graphitus)
- [Graph-Explorer](https://github.com/Dieterbe/graph-explorer)
- [Graphene](http://jondot.github.com/graphene/)
- [Graphiti](https://github.com/paperlesspost/graphiti)
- [Graphsky](https://github.com/hyves-org/graphsky)
- [Pencil](https://github.com/fetep/pencil)
- [Tasseo](https://github.com/obfuscurity/tasseo)

Additional interesting resources:

- [Graphitoid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tnc.android.graphite): (an Android-App dashboard)
- [Graphitejs](https://github.com/prestontimmons/graphitejs): (a jQuery plugin for making/displaying Graphite graphs)
- [Seyren](https://github.com/scobal/seyren): (an alerting dashboard for Graphite)

For details on each one, check out their pages, or take a look at the description on the first link I added, for the [Graphite docs page](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tools.html).

Answer (score 95):

Try [Grafana](http://grafana.org)

It has a very nice UI and advanced dashboard and graph editing features. Very simple to install.

[image]

Comment: Grafana is definitely the best one! One feature that is missing though is notifications.

Comment: great work - I'm trying to set it up with Nginx and Graphite but not able to get any data from graphite -any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374405/unable-to-configure-grafana-with-graphite

Comment: @Felix notifications, what do you mean?

Comment: Basically, I mean alerts. But I see, that Grafana is a client-side dashboard and it is not designed for that. Nevertheless, alerts are a important piece of the puzzle in the graphite/metrics domain. Dashboards are pretty, but automation for threshold checking is crucial for efficiency - especially, if you've got a lot of metrics. So some sort of integration with alerting systems would be nice.

Comment: @Felix there are Notifications now

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to code up your own frontend, you can use [Graphiti](https://github.com/paperlesspost/graphiti). It is simple to use and looks great!

[image: Graphiti Screenshot]

Answer (score 13):

A-ha! I did some googling and found [Cubism.js](http://square.github.com/cubism/) which does exactly what I need.

It has integrated [support for graphite](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Graphite) and provides the necessary graphing components (as a plugin to [D3](http://d3js.org/)) to create [beautiful real-time dashboards](http://square.github.com/cubism/demo/).

Answer (score 6):

I can see this is a bit old, but thought I'd add to it for future prosperity:

I went through a few of the options listed in @troy's response (and a few others). You can see my impressions in [my blog post](http://dashboarddude.com/blog/2013/01/23/dashboards-for-graphite/)

Comment: That's a great comparison of the available options.  +1!

Comment: Please include the relevant info into this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Graphene which is a layer above Graphite:
http://jondot.github.com/graphene/

Answer (score 2):

Anyone tried Orion? Seems to be a good option but overlooked so far.
 https://github.com/gree/Orion

Comment: Orion looks nice, but seems quite stale as a project. It lacks some fundamental features, at least support for using Graphite functions.