# unable to configure grafana with graphite

Tags: nginx, graphite

I am using Nginx to serve both graphite and grafana (they are all running on the same server - not my desktop).  I am able to access graphite via Nginx.  However, grafana cannot seem to connect to graphite (error: Graphite HTTP Request Error).  I have copied the nginx config below for grafana - any ideas on fixing this will be appreciated. 
The request URL that fails in the browser is this (accessible if I access it directly in the browser):

```
**http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/render**
```

**Nginx default**

```
server { 
        listen 85;  ##listen [::]:85; #ipv6only=on;
        server_name grafana;
        root /home/xxxx/grafana-1.5.3/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        ##logging per server
        access_log /var/log/nginx/grafana/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/grafana/error.log;

       location / {
       ##  root /home/xxxx/grafana-1.5.3/;
       }
}
```

**config.js URL for graphite (in grafana)**

```
graphiteUrl: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080"
```

**Edit**
Graphite does not need authentication for access from grafana.  Also, I am using grafana v1.5.3

Comment: I am having this issue as well.  Did you ever find any work around for this?

Comment: @jmreicha got sidetracked - will look into it later this week with the answers provided below and post an update here.  I think all three answers provide useful information in solving this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to access graphite through nginx (same origin). Just add new location

```
location /render {
                proxy_pass      http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/render;
}
```

then in your grafana config file change graphite url

Comment: I added '/render' in the server portion of the nginx default conf file for grafana - the get request still fails.

Comment: The post call to the graphite URL (ON PORT 8080) from app.js (render call) fails.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run browser whith "disable-web-security" flag.

Comment: In the current version of phantomjs, I had to use --web-security=false to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem by changing the requests to GET instead of POST. See this issue for more information.  https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/345

My data sources ended up looking like

```
datasources: {
  graphite: {
    type: 'graphite',
    url: window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+window.location.port+"/_graphite",
    default: true,
    render_method: 'GET'  
  },
},
```

I still haven't figured out how to get my graphite install to accept POST requests. Even when querying directly so I can be sure CORS isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to enable CORS in nginx configuration for **graphite**.Take a look at : http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html . Here's the configuration I made using this link:

(In my case, grafana is exposed on port `8100`, and graphite on port `8090`; adapt accordingly (`8100` -> `85` , `8090` -> `8080`) ).

```
upstream django {
    # Distribute requests to servers based on client IP. This keeps load
    # balancing fair but consistent per-client. In this instance we're
    # only using one uWGSI worker anyway.
    ip_hash;
    server unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}

server {
   listen      yourServerIp:8090;
   server_name yourServerName.com;
   access_log      /var/log/nginx/graphite_access.log;
   error_log       /var/log/nginx/graphite_error.log;
   charset     utf-8;


   # Django admin media.
   location /media/admin/ {
      alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/;
   }

   # Static media.
   location /content/ {
      alias /opt/graphite/webapp/content/;
   }

   # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
   location / {

    # CORS (for grafana)

    if ($http_origin ~* "^http://yourServerName.com:8100$") {
     set $cors "true";
    }

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
     set $cors "${cors}options";  
    }

    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
     set $cors "${cors}get";  
    }

    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
     set $cors "${cors}post";
    }

    if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
     add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
     add_header 'Content-Length' 0;

     return 204;
    }

    if ($cors = "truepost") {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    }

    if ($cors = "trueget") {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    }

     uwsgi_pass  django;
     include     uwsgi_params;
   }
}
```

Note that the interesting part for you is what's below `# CORS` , the django stuff might be useless for you.

To ensure it's a CORS issue, you want to inspect HTTP headers sent by your browser; if there's a `Origin` header, it means you have to use CORS.

Comment: thanks for sharing - I tried it.  I think I might have to check how graphite is configured on this box.  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/render still fails.  Most likely, I need to check how I've misconfigured graphite.

Comment: Can you give us a quick insight on what the http request and response headers look like ? It might help

Comment: it is a CORS issue - the post request to graphite gets rejected due to cross origin issue.

Comment: This problem is a cors issue (chrome and firefox confirm this)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to try would be to use a CORS proxy if you cannot edit the NGinx config.
I used the NPM package corsproxy to get around the graphite CORS issue.

Install the corsproxy package:

```
 mkdir graphiteProxy
 cd graphiteProxy
 npm install corsproxy
 echo "copy the version of http_proxy corsproxy depends on into"
 echo "your local node_modules"
 cp -r node_modules\corsproxy\node_modules\http-proxy node_modules\http_proxy
 touch app.js
```

app.js:

```
// point the grafana config.js to your local proxy: http://localhost:8081
var cors_proxy = require('corsproxy')
var http_proxy = require('http-proxy')
cors_proxy.options = {
   target : "http://{{graphiteserver}}:8080"
}
http_proxy.createServer(cors_proxy).listen(8081)
```

run the proxy:

```
node app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the nginx config file I use to host both grafana and proxy graphite and elasticsearch.

```
 server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
      root /src/grafana;
      index index.html;
    }
    location /graphite/ {
        proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location /elasticsearch/ {
        proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:9200/;
        proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will most certainly do when I get back onto that installation - I was not able to look into the installation earlier.  Much appreciated

Comment: Based on my setup, just using the root and index options under the location setting do not work.  I get a HTTP request error frmo app.js (in the render call).  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/render (8080 is where grafite is running).  Do I need to change any config in grafana or graphite to make this work?

Comment: The issue (I think) is that I have a domain name for this server which I use to access the applications on it (including graphite and grafana).  When I try directly with the URL, my existing setup works (I will try the CORS option mentioned by Colin when I get the chance).  Once again, thanks for sharing

Comment: I tried this (without the elasticsearch block) and get "Error Could not load dashboards/default.json. Please make sure it exists". I'm not exactly sure which directory your `root` is pointing to and wonder if that could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the OP has resolved their problem yet or not, but here's what worked for me:

I put graphite and grafana on the same site. Graphite exists at the root and grafana within /grafana/

This solves the cross site scripting problem without having to setup CORS: graphite and grafana are on the same site.

nginx site configuration:

```
upstream graphite {
    server unix:///var/uwsgi/graphite-web.sock;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080 ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/graphite-web/;

    server_name localhost;

    location /static {
            alias /usr/share/graphite-web/static;
    }

    location /grafana {
            alias /usr/share/graphite-web/grafana;
    }


    location / {
            uwsgi_pass graphite;
            include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

To access grafana, I therefore go to:

```
http://192.168.1.1:8080/grafana
```

(192.168.1.1 is my server's ip address)